# Can I run a 64-bit VMware image on a 32-bit machine?

Tags: 64-bit, vmware, virtualization, virtual-machine

Can I run a 64-bit VMware image on a 32-bit machine?

I've googled this, but there doesn't seem to be a conclusive answer.

I know that it would have to be completely emulated and would run like a dog - but slow performance isn't necessarily an issue as I'm just interested in testing some of my background services code on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: I can give you a way to install a [64 bit based virtual machine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFtRw38VIc4&feature=youtu.be) without even having a hypervisor installed like vmware or hyper v.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The easiest way to check your workstation is to download the [VMware Processor Check for 64-Bit Compatibility](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/processor_check_5_5_dt/dCpiQGhkYmRAZQ==) tool from the VMware website.

You can't run a 64-bit VM session on a 32-bit processor.  However, you can run a 64-bit VM session if you have a 64-bit processor but have installed a 32-bit host OS and your processor supports the right extensions.  The tool linked above will tell you if yours does.

Comment: The link above no longer takes you to a page that references the processor check tool. Here's a direct link: http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/processor_check_for_64_bit_compatibility_6_0/JWpiQHBqYiVo

Comment: @Phil Ross - Thanks!  I have updated the link in the answer with the URL you posted.

Comment: So you're saying that VMWare itself can't do it.  But you could convert the image to a qemu image as explained by dbr.  Or (given sufficient RAM) run VMWare from within a 64-bit host VM that was in turn a VM running in qemu or another VM utility that emulates a 64-bit processor.  Complicated, but to say flat-out that it's not possible is incorrect.

Comment: Here's the link for both the Windows & Linux versions as well: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details/processor_check_5_5_dt/JSpiQGhkYmRwKg

Answer (score 30):

If you have 32-bit hardware, no, you cannot run a 64-bit guest OS. ["VMware software does not emulate an instruction set for different hardware not physically present"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware#Core_product_design).

However, QEMU *can* emulate a 64-bit processor, so you could convert the VMWare machine and run it with this

From [this 2008-era blog post (mirrored by archive.org)](http://web.archive.org/web/20080529004826/http://blog.xwings.net/?p=47):

> ```
> $ cd /path/to/vmware/guestos
> $ for i in \`ls *[0-9].vmdk\`; do qemu-img convert -f vmdk $i -O raw {i/vmdk/raw};done
> $ cat *.raw >> guestos.img
> ```
>
> To run it,
>
> ```
> qemu -m 256 -hda guestos.img
> ```
>
> The downside? Most of us runs VMware without preallocation space for the virtual disk. So, when we make a conversion from VMware to QEMU, the raw file will be the total space WITH preallocation. I am still testing with `-f qcow` format will it solve the 
>   problem or not. Such as:
>
> ```
> for i in `ls *[0-9].vmdk`; do qemu-img convert -f vmdk $i -O qcow ${i/vmdk/qcow}; done && cat *.qcow >> debian.img
> ```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, running a 64-bit OS in VMWare is possible from a 32-bit OS if you have a 64 bit processor.

I have an old Intel [Core 2 Duo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_2_Duo) with Windows XP Professional 2002 running on it, and I got it to work.

First of all, see if your CPU is capable of running a 64-bit OS. Search for 'Processor check for 64-bit compatibility' on the VMware site. Run the program.

If it says your processor is capable, restart your computer and go into the BIOS and see if you have 'Virtualization' and are able to enable it. I was able to and got [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 running under VMware on this old laptop.

I hope it works for you!

Comment: Core 2 Duo is a 64-bit processor. It's interesting that it can run in VMWare on the 32-bit version of Windows XP.

Comment: First you say that you can run a 64-bit OS on a 32-bit processor and then you say that you should check if your processor is 64-bit?

Comment: i am using 32 bit,2GB RAM,windows 7.Hey My VM is giving this error   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LzXNh-gDLNVml5bHl0clZIdUk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 8):

If your hardware is 32-bit only, then no. If you have 64 bit hardware and a 32-bit operating system, then maybe. See *[Hardware and Firmware Requirements for 64-Bit Guest Operating Systems](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/dynamickc.do?externalId=1901&sliceId=1&command=show&forward=nonthreadedKC&kcId=1901)* for details. It has nothing to do with one vs. multiple processors.

Answer (score 4):

It boils down to whether the CPU in your machine has the the VT bit (Virtualization), and the BIOS enables you to turn it on. For instance, my laptop is a *[Core 2 Duo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_2_Duo)* which is capable of using this. However, my BIOS doesn't enable me to turn it on.

Note that I've read that turning on this feature can slow normal operations down by 10-12%, which is why it's normally turned off.

Answer (score 3):

I honestly doubt it, for a number of reasons, but the most important one is that there are some instructions that are allowed in 32-bit mode, but not in 64-bit mode.  Specifically, the REX prefix that is used to encode some instructions and registers in 64-bit mode is a byte of the form 0x4f:0x40, but in 32 bit mode the same byte is either INC or DEC with a fixed operand.
Because of this, any 64-bit instruction that is prefixed by REX will be interpreted as either INC or DEC, and won't give the VMM the chance to emulate the 64-bit instruction (for instance by signaling an undefined opcode exception).

The only way it might be done is to use a trap exception to return to the VMM after each and every instruction so that it can see if it needs special 64-bit handling.  I simply can't see that happening.

Comment: VMWare wouldn't need such a trap system.  When they aren't using hardware virtualization support, they check each basic block for privileged instructions and replace them with calls to their handlers.  They /could/ do the same for x64 instructions, but that'd make it an emulator -- not their thing.

Answer (score 3):

VMware? No. However, [QEMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) has an x86_64 system target that you can use. You likely won't be able to use a VMware image directly (IIRC, there's no conversion tool), but you can install the OS and such yourself and work inside it. QEMU can be a bit of a PITA to get up and running, but it tends to work quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

VMware does not allow you to run a 64-bit guest on a 32-bit host. You just have to read the documentation to find this out.

If you really want to do this, you can use QEMU, and I recommend a Linux host, but it's going to be very slow (I really mean slow).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. I have a 64-bit Debian running in VMware on Windows XP 32-Bit. As long as you set the Guest to use two processors, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can if your processor is 64-bit and Virtualization Technology (VT) extension is enabled (it can be switched off in BIOS). You can't do it on 32-bit processor.

To check this under Linux you just need to look into */proc/cpuinfo* file. Just look for the appropriate flag (**vmx** for Intel processor or **svm** for AMD processor)

```
egrep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

To check this under Windows you need to use a program like CPU-Z which will display your processor architecture and supported extensions.

Comment: As far as I understand John want to run the VM on 32 bit processor