# is it possible to run 64 bit code in a machine with 32 bit processor?

Tags: c, compilation, 32-bit, cpu-registers, processor

I have searched around to get the answers for these questions. but not much luck.

1. Is it possible to run `32-bit` code in a machine with `64-bit processor`?

   The answer seems to be yes. but there is a debate on performance issues, since `32-bits` are left unused on the processor.
2. Now my question is vice-versa, Is it possible to run `64-bit` code in a machine with `32-bit` processor?

   from my little understanding, the answer is NO, because the code designed to run on `64-bit`
   will be using `64-process registars` but the `32-bit` machine offers only 32.

On the otherhand, I found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f21450f5-b36d-4ea2-9806-f169aff0388d/compiling-for-64-bit-on-a-32-bit-machine?forum=netfx64bit). According this, it is possible to compile  64-bit code on a 32-bit machine. But I am not clear on how this is done  plus  if compiling on a `32-bit` machine will also guarantee `execution` on the same.

Thanks for helping out

Comment: "According this, it is possible to compile 64-bit code on a 32-bit machine." - yes, it's perfectly possible. It's called cross-compilation. But that has nothing to do with what code/executables a 32-bit machine can run.

Comment: Pedantically speaking: Both 32-bit and 64-bit machines are turing machines. So they can run emulate each other...

Comment: @Mysticial: what does that exactly mean? not clear what you mean here..

Comment: @user1988876 QEMU can emulate a 64-bit processor on a 32-bit host architecture - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/56332/2864740 (but few end-users are likely willing to run a parallel OS)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it possible to run 32-bit code in a machine with 64-bit processor?

Yes.  This is handled in Windows via [WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example.

> Now my question is vice-versa, Is it possible to run 64-bit code in a machine with 32-bit processor?

No.  64bit code would require a 64 bit instruction set, which won't be available on a 32 bit processor.

> According this, it is possible to compile 64-bit code on a 32-bit machine.

You can *compile* code for other architectures, but not *execute* it.  This lets you build code for different platforms than the currently executing platform, but executing it will not work.

Comment: awesome! but then the last part would guarantee, `write once, run anywhere` rather than `write once, compile anywhere`.

Comment: @user1988876 If you're thinking in terms of Java (or other "managed" style languages), you compile to an intermediate toolset, which then can execute "anywhere" (with the appropriate execution platform) - in Java case, you compile to java byte code, which can be run on any JVM (in theory).

Comment: @user1988876 I also didn't get into possible executing via emulators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator  I suspect this isn't what you were after, though.

Comment: lets say, I compile my code for 32-bit machines and 64-bit machines from my 32-bit computer. I can ship this compiled code to outside world. Those with 32-bit PC download 32-bit executable and others the 64-bit one. so here,`write Once, run anywhere` could be done..is something not correct with my understanding here?

Comment: @user1988876 Yes, that could be possible (though shipping *untested* code would be unethical IMO)

Comment: Thanks. would it be correct to say `compilation is architecture independent`?

Comment: @user1988876 Compilation *can be* architecture independent.  It completely depends on the compiler.  Compilation is just transforming data from one form to another, which could (in theory) happen on any platform/architecture/etc.