# Unable to execute binary file

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

I recently heard about **[Breach](http://breach.cc/)**, a Node.js based browser. I was following the instructions on http://codeforgeek.com/2014/08/download-install-breach-browser-ubuntu-14-04/ to install it but got the following error :

**breach-v0.3.22-alpha.6-linux-x64/__AUTO_UPDATE_BUNDLE__/exo_browser/exo_browser: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error**

After some googling, I found that it is because I am trying to install the 64 bit package on the 32 bit Ubuntu installation. I tried to find 32 bit package of the same but ended up with no luck. The browser is only available in 64 bit packet(as far as i know).

So, My question is :

Is it possible to somehow install it on the 32 bit OS or if any program available which can run 64 bit applications on the 32 bit OS.

I have been googling around and found no help. Can anyone help me?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (32 Bit).

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar  problem with c files .I think it has some thing to do with the compiler which we use 
My kernel version is

3.13.0-40-generic

which you get by executing the command uname -r  in terminal .

I had a code file which does file operations. When I used GCC with   appropriate    flags  and created an object file called "fileop" and tried   running it
I  got the following error .
"bash: ./fileop: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"
My executable linkable file was 32bit which you can see by using command
"file fileop"
fileop: ELF 32-bit LSB  relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

But when I used "CC" instead of GCC, It created a out file called a.out and I   was able to execute it without any issues.
The "file" operation yielded the following ouput
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically   linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]  =13b7ad302580a0c7f5c7931ec2d80155d7915fa9, not stripped

Hope the above Description sheds more light in to the  issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to (directly) run 64 bit binaries on the 32 bit system.

You **could** try to use VMWare to run 64 bit Linux on the 32 bit host. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56198/782609) for details.

Also, by inspecting Breach's landing page, I found this:

```
  if(arch === 'ia32') {
    $('#download').html('Available on <span class="fa fa-linux"></span> x64');
    $('#download').attr('href', '#');
    /*
    $('#download').html('<span class="fa fa-linux"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Download Breach Alpha v0.3 (ia32)');
    $('#download').attr('href', 'http://bit.ly/1kWWjmF');
    */
  }
```

This indicates that they are working on the 32 bit Linux support. Maybe ask developers on Twitter/Github on status of that?